# How can I style specific symbols in an element?

Tags: css

Is it possible to have the quotes in the following HTML bold and red, without altering the HTML code?

```
<div class="client_message">&ldquo; Ankit &rdquo;</div>
```

Basically I would like to have some CSS that results in the same effect as
"Ankit" but these quotes must be in bold.

Is this possible with CSS only?

Comment: If it were semantically correct HTML (e.g `<div><q>Ankit</q></div>`) it would be very easy to achieve this. However, this is something you cannot achieve, at least not for the last letter (the first can be addressed by `.client_message:first-letter`).

Comment: You can do it, but it's an ugly hack where you position your CSS created quotes to overlap the ones that are already there, check my answer.

Comment: Why don’t you simply wrap the quotation marks inside `span` elements and style them? That’s simpler and far more robust than any trickery you might need (and trickery would you need).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. CSS has *very* limited capability when it comes to selecting things which are not elements.

The nearest CSS has is [`::first-letter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter), but that would select `&ldquo; A`.

Comment: css has a content property and a :before and :after selector class, you can use these to insert and style the quotes

Comment: @LastCoder — The question is asking how to style quotes that are in the content (and cannot be changed), not how to add more.

Comment: @Quentin: TIL *"Punctuation (i.e, characters defined in Unicode in the "open" (Ps), "close" (Pe), "initial" (Pi). "final" (Pf) and "other" (Po) punctuation classes), that precedes or follows the first letter should be included"*. CSS sure has its pitfalls.

Comment: @Zeta — I said that already, and that isn't a pitfall, it makes perfect sense for what `::first-letter` is designed for. The problem is that CSS has nothing that is designed for this use case.

Comment: But this will also make the same changes in with A of ankit.but i only want to change the qoutes ...

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal — Read the first sentence of this answer again.

Comment: You obviously can't do the impossible (styling specific text within a single text node in CSS) but you can fiddle with positioning and make it look acceptable.

Comment: Then what about the last Quote?? @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

```
div.client_message:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: visible;
    left: .0em;
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: "“";
}
div.client_message:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: visible;
    right: .0em;
    color: red;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: "”";
}
div.client_message {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

css has a content property and a :before and :after selector class, you can use these to insert and style the quotes.

**note** CSS content property is not supported is old IE's less than version 9 http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

**EDIT You have to do a bit of fudging in the CSS but you can get it to work** http://jsfiddle.net/wtceu/

**EDIT 2** I've put a background-color so that the tails from the HTML entity quotes don't show through the new overlapped quotes. The only issue is if the text takes up more than one line, the ending quote won't position correctly (you can reproduce this by shrinking the width of the jsfiddle window).

Comment: Now there are two sets of quotes around the content, and only one set is styled as desired.

Comment: @Quentin - using the positioning properties you can make this look correctly by overlapping the CSS added quotes over the ones that are present in the markup.

Comment: That sounds extremely fragile and not even slightly resistant to differing fonts on different systems. Interesting idea though.

Comment: @Quentin - the styling and position rules work the same on most browsers, the major flaw is that it cannot handle multiple lines of text. The more difficult the constraints added to the problem the more fragile the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript you could change the HTML to

```
<div><q>Ankit</q></div>
```

(mentioned in comment before)

Now selecting the elements is easy

```
q {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 .client_message:before {color: red;font-weight: bold;content: "“";}

 .client_message:after {color: red;font-weight: bold;content: "”";}
```

Comment: I've tried this on a host server, and it worked until I republished, when it trashed punctuation on the site and on my publisher. Had to delete and start over with Meyer. Maybe css4 and/or html6 will improve?

Comment: Your suggestion (in my experience incomplete) is nicely expanded in Meyer, Css The Definitive Guide 4, page 788. If you don't have a copy yet, you can download at the link provided. Your approach done properly, enables the no-close-quote styling for quotation containing paragraphs...   blockquote {quotes: '"' '"' "'" "'" '"' '"';} blockquote p::before {content: open-quote;} blockquote p::after {content: no-close-quote;}

Answer (score -1):

Quotes require ‘possessive’ punctuation. In “[Css The Definitive Guide 4][1]”, pp. 786-788, Eric Meyer describes ‘Generated quotes’.

With quotes, you can define quotation patterns to as many nesting levels as you like. In English, for example, a common practice is to start out with a double quotation mark, and a quotation nested inside the first one gets single quotation marks. This can be recreated with “curly” quotation marks using the following rules:

```
quotation { color: forestgreen; display: block; }
quote { display: block; quotes: '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019'; }
quote::before, q::before { content: open-quote; }
quote::after, q::after { content: close-quote; }

<quotation>
<quote>
    In the beginning, there was nothing. 
    And God said:
    <q>
        Let there be light!
    </q>
  And <abbr>there&rsquo;s</abbr> some light, that’s [Mac keyb] good.
</quote>
The Holy Bible, Creation
</quotation>
```

“In the beginning, there was nothing. And God said: ‘Let there be light!’ And there was light.”

The hypotheses (nor acronyms) used in English abbreviation contractions do not respond to Meyer's simple quotation CSS. That's where &rsquo; and &rdquo; are  useful, working with the quotation, [**abbr** and **acronnym**][2] elements. Note that ABBR element (e.g., WHO) is distinct from the abbr attribute (it's one, he's done).

Note also that Apple device keyboards use **Option** and **Shift-Option** keys pressed-together with **[** and **]** keys to generate English opening and closing curly quotes respectively, *in this and many other web environments*. Meyer's CSS and simpler Apple keyboard shortcuts work well for ‹other languages›, such as French quotation punctuations.

Other devices and networks may similarly adapt or even block the simple display of HTML and CSS quotation code (and related punctuation). There's nothing wrong with offering HTML/CSS guidance, where appropriate. Curly quote styling can encompass more than simple quotes.

[1]: https://itebooksfree.com/book/css-the-definitive-guide-4th-edition/31410. Meyer and Weyl ©2018.

[2]: https://maxdesign.com.au/news/abbreviations/ ...no discussion of block elements that are a foundation of written language quotations. Contraction and quotation, CSS technology character string focus tends to ignore mainstream curly quotes development. Meyer being an important exception.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly we can accomplish far more than most are aware of, without almost scripted neglect in our collective knowledge base. As an aside, it would be nice if Stack quotation marks were more legible.

Moving forward, perhaps to cover our bases better, the CSS should look like this.

```
quotation { color: forestgreen; display: block; }
quote { display: block; quotes: '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019'; }
quote::before, q::before { content: open-quote; }
quote::after, q::after { content: close-quote; }
quote { quotes: '\201C' '\201D'; }
blockquote { quotes: '"' '"' "'" "'" '"' '"'; } 
blockquote p::before { content: open-quote; } 
blockquote p::after { content: no-close-quote; }
```

Google finds many people unable to style the simple quotes. Still looking for contraction code: i.e., **root’extension** possessive single right curly quote styling. Can current DOM handle contraction single right quote without script... what's that trick?